# eclipse java development - adding a private static final String TAG automatically to each new class

Tags: eclipse, development-environment

Is it possible in eclipse to add a tag field

```
private static final String TAG = "MyClass";
```

automatically to each newly create class. Not a big deal to type it but having this automatically added would definitely increase my *adding log info discipline*  ...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible
Go to **Window - Preferrences**
[image: sample]

So newly created files will have this line.

But it will be more useful if you make
[image: smaple2]

then in code just print **mytag** and press Ctrl + Space

Comment: great - so the last bit would be to know how to replace MyClass with the name of the actual class, is this possible?

Comment: just found private static final String TAG = "${file_name}"; which is okay :-)

Comment: private static final String TAG = "${type_name}"; for the first case and private static final String TAG = "${primary_type_name}";for the second

Answer (score 1):

Some improvement. You can use "enclosing_type" variable in your tag:

```
private static final String TAG = "${enclosing_type}";
```