# Can Androidstudio generate TAG at the start of a new class?

Tags: android, android-studio

Eclipse can insert a

```
private static final String TAG = "ThisClass"
```

at the beginning of every newly created class body, see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832141/eclipse-java-development-adding-a-private-static-final-string-tag-automaticall).

Can AndroidStudio somehow do the same?

Answer (score 9):

Inside Android Studio preferences go to Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Class. This defines the template for each new class you create. Inside the class object add the following line:

```
private static final String TAG = "$NAME";
```

This will add the `TAG` string to each new class with the class name as its value.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.